# xdebug - is there a quicker / easier way to load / unload this?

Tags: xdebug

Is there a way to quickly load / unload xdebug from Apache?

At the moment, I:

- open up php.ini
- comment / uncomment the 4 xdebug-related lines
- restart Apache

which takes time.

Comment: If you find yourself enabling and disabling xdebug all the time, why not leave it disabled but loaded, and enable it with [the trigger](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#profiler_enable_trigger)?

Comment: @xathien is there going to be any performance overhead with that?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the version of PHP you are using. If you are on 5.4+, you should be able to run this:

```
# php5dismod xdebug && apachectl -k graceful
```

And to enable:

```
# php5enmod xdebug && apachectl -k graceful
```

Comment: I don't have php5dismod on my Mac. Is there something else I should install?

Comment: What's your PHP version? You should be able to see it by running `php --version`. Are you using MAMP?